# R markdown output size

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I want to generate a R markdown page with an interactive shiny app. It works fine but the output is in a really small area with scrollbars. I want to get rid of the scrollbars and show the 2 figures with full width and height without scrollbars. How can I achieve that?

I have already tried:

```
options(width = 800)
```

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

````
    ---
title: "Spielercluster"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

data<-read.csv2('data.csv',header=T,sep=",") 
rawData<-read.csv2('rawData.csv',header=T,sep=",")
cluster<-read.csv2('cluster.csv',header=T,sep=",")
colors<-c("green","red","black")

ui<-fluidPage(plotOutput("plot1", hover = "plot_hover"),
              plotOutput("plot2", hover = "plot_hover"),
              verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
ggplot(rawData, aes(koerpergewicht, groesse, color =  factor(data$gruppe))) +
          geom_point() + labs(title = paste(nlevels(factor(colors))))+geom_point(size=8)+geom_text(aes(label=position),vjust=-1.5)+scale_color_manual(name = "Gruppe",
  labels = c("1 schwer", "2 leicht","3 Zwischengruppe"),
  values = c(rgb(0.9725490196078431,0.4627450980392157,0.4274509803921569,1),rgb(0,0.7294117647058824,0.2196078431372549,1),rgb(0.3803921568627451,0.6117647058823529,1,1)))+ggtitle("Original")
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
ggplot(rawData, aes(koerpergewicht, groesse, color =  factor(cluster$x))) +
          geom_point() + labs(title = paste(nlevels(factor(colors))))+geom_point(size=8)+geom_text(aes(label=position),vjust=-1.5)+scale_color_manual(name = "Gruppe",
  labels = c("1 schwer", "2 leicht","3 Zwischengruppe"),
  values = c(rgb(0.9725490196078431,0.4627450980392157,0.4274509803921569,1),rgb(0,0.7294117647058824,0.2196078431372549,1),rgb(0.3803921568627451,0.6117647058823529,1,1)))+ggtitle("Berechnet")
  })


  output$info <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(rawData, input$plot_hover, , threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I achieved it by adding my own css file. You can include it like this:

```
---
title: "Spielercluster"
output:
  html_document:
    css: style.css
runtime: shiny
---
```

Then you have to adjust the sizes of the class **shiny-frame**

```
.shiny-frame{
  width: 1400px;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(height = 1000)`

> Note the use of the height parameter to determine how much vertical space the 
>   embedded application should occupy. (http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on `R Shiny Server Pro 1.5.11.994`, and CentOs 7.5.

After dabbling with server `options`, figure dimensions (Eg, `fig.width`, or `fig.fullwidth`), and plot dimensions, what ultimately worked for me was CSS.

Here's the top of my markdown file:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    css: my_styles.css
---
```

and then in `my_styles.css`:

```
div.main-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.shiny-frame {
  height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: doesn't change anything for me

Answer (score 0):

When turn the shiny into Markdown file, I think you should delete the server and UI function because this is not a regular rmarkdown file, then it will show the whole shiny graphics. I have solved this problem by doing in this way.
you can change the shiny into this formate.

Here is a link: [change shiny format into rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html#overview)

Comment: could you post the cleaned up version of the code, you used to solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

To set globally

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 12, fig.height=8)
```

or locally for each output

````
```{r,echo=FALSE, fig.width = 12, fig.height=8}
````

should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything

Comment: `fig.width` etc does nothing for the size at which the plots are rendered.